# Как отправить форму, если кнопка  submit скрыта?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Задача такая: я скрыл кнопку для кастомизации, теперь не пойму, как отправить форму. Вроде функция с jquery submit() должна помочь, но ничего не выходит, помогите.

Answer (score 7):

Даже если кнопка сабмит скрыта, то `jquery.submit()` должен работать:

```js
//тем временем в jQuery
$("#real_smb").click(function() {
  $("#myform").submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="test.php" method="post" id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="login">
  <input type="submit" value="ok" style="display:none">
  <input type="button" value="real OK" id="real_smb">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Чтоб отправить форму вам всё равно надо будет выполнить нажатие кнопки.

Например можно воспользоваться html-тегом `<div>`, которому можно задать некий стиль. Например:

```
<div class="my_style" onClick="submit();">текст кнопки</div>
```

Учтите, эту div-кнопку обязательно надо писать в форме, которую собираетесь отправить!

По идее можно воспользоваться и таким методом:

```
<div id="my_id" style="display:none;" onClick="submit();">текст кнопки</div>
```

А в JavaScript-е при определённых, заданных, условиях сделать такую запись:

```
document.getElementById('my_id').click();
```

В таком случае кнопку видно не будет, и форма будет отправляться при выполнении условий. По идее должно работать. Если не выходит - пишите, разберём.

Третий вариант, это создавать событие `onKeyPress` в строке ввода данных формы. При нажатии клавиши `Enter` выполнять функцию `submit();`.

P.S.: первый метод точно должен работать, проверено не раз.

Comment: > задан 26 Ноя '11

Comment: @Fike, Чёрт. И бывает же. Только что посмотрел вторую его тему, тоже старая. Эхх. А я расписывал. Ладно, другим останется, вдруг кто-то наткнётся и ему полезно будет почитать. :)

Comment: @intro94,

>  которому можно задать некий стиль.
> Например:
> 
>     <div class="my_style" onClick="submit();">текст кнопки</div>

Это называется классом, подучите терминологию. Во-вторых, топикстартер просил jQuery код, на что намекает соответствующая метка. В-третьих, не надо писать обработчики событий в HTML коде, если для этого нет веских причин, хороший тон -- вынести все скрипты в подключаемые файлы, для упрощения восприятия кода.

Comment: @Risto я не сомневаюсь в ваших знаниях, но ставить минус репутации за то, что вам не понравился ответ, это дурной тон.
Первое: терминологию я знаю. Не всегда ею пользуюсь, так как не все её могут знать. CSS и HTML я знаю хорошо.
Второе: ТС не просил решение именно на jQuery. Внимательно почтайте - он просит решение поблемы. Он попробовал jQuery, но у него не получилось. Вот что он на этот счёт писал.
Третье: писать обработчики событий в html-коде это дело каждого. Для кого-то это дурной тон, а для кого-то это удобно. ТС спросил варианты - я ему накидал вариантов. Неправы вы в данной ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

> Можно имитировать нажатие на кнопку

`$("#myform").trigger('click');`

Comment: > задан 26 Ноя '11